# Accessibility issues with navigation drawers - using support library 21

Tags: android, accessibility, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I upgraded support library from 19 to 21:-

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+
com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+
```

Since `v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated, I changed it to 
`android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Everything in the app works fine except that navigation drawer items are not accessible, not clickable when `talkBack` is enabled. Rest of the app is accessible.

Has anyone experienced this?

Here,
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

for Android support library 19.1.0 (march 2014) changes include :

> Fixed accessibility issues with navigation drawers

Is it possible that this fix did not come in support library 21?

Thanks!

The code being used is:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

drawer_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_rdcgetstarted"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="com.myapp.activities.fragment.AccountDetailsFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_layout"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The included navigation_drawer is common for all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
    android:divider="@color/navigation_item_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/navigation_list_selector"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: Could be a bug in the support library. On what OS version are you seeing this issue? What is your app's targetSdkVersion?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 21. So far i have tested on Samsung Note-II: OS 4.1.2 and Samsung Galaxy S5 4.4.4

Comment: Do you have the standard content view and nav drawer view inside your drawer layout, or more than two views?

Comment: So, this is how DrawerLayout is used:
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

Comment: posting the code now..

Comment: Almost definitely a bug in support library. Would you mind filing an issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?

Comment: Not sure why I am not able to paste my code, but to answer your question:  in the drawer_layout there is a framelayout that includes a fragment for the activity and then i include a navigation_drawer. So, each activity in the app has its own drawer_layout, but navigation_drawer is common.

Comment: Thanks alanv. Sure, i will file this issue. How/when will know the issue is fixed?